# Add textview using ARCore

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

Im using ARCore with Android Studio, and managed to place 3D object with following code. Id like to know whether its possible to add text view (text box) and if so how? Appreciate any input!

```
 virtualObject.createOnGlThread(this, "models/andy.obj", "models/andy.png");
 virtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.5f, 6.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add text to your ARCore scene. You can use a ViewRenderable and there you can place a textview widget. Google has a page about it here:

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables